# Doubt in stokes theorem Curve direction

Tags: vector-analysis

**verify stoke's theorem for $F=xz \vec i - y \vec j +x^2y \vec k $ where S is surface of region bounded by $x =0, y=0, 2x+y+2z=8$ which is not included in xz plane
I am confused over magnitude(moving along curve so that surface is in left hand side)**

My attempt

$\iint_{S_1+S_2} Curl \vec F \cdot \vec n = \iiint div Curl \vec F dV = 0 \implies \iint_{S_1} =- \iint_{S_2}$

$S_2 $ --> i am taking in direction so that normal $\vec n = -\vec k$

In this case i am getting $\iint_{S_2} = \frac{-32}{3} \implies \iint_{S_1} = - (\frac{-32}{3})=(\frac{32}{3}) $

**Now calculating single integral $\int_C \vec F.d\vec r$**

Now how should i take direction? I took in following way but i am getting sign change. can you pls have a look?

Single integrals along $\vec {OA}, \vec {BO}$ i am getting zero.

For single integral along $\vec {AB}$:

$y=0, x+z = 4 \implies dx = -dz \implies \int_C \vec F \cdot d \vec r = \int_C F.(-dz \vec i+0 \vec j+dz \vec k)$ where $F = xz \vec i - y \vec j +x^2y \vec k$

So, $\int_C \vec F.d\vec r = \int^4_{z=0} (-xz+x^2y)dz , y =0 \implies $ integral = $\int^4_{z=0} (-(4-z)z)dz = \frac{-32}{3} $

**i am gettting negative sign. how should i identify direction of C quickly without confusion**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the right-hand rule convention, the contour $C$ that bounds the open surface of interest is comprised of the line segment from (i) $(4,0,0)$ to $(0,0,0)$, (ii) $(0,0,0)$ to $(0,0,4)$, and (iii) the line segment from $(0,0,4)$ to $(4,0,0)$$

The line integral of $\vec F$ on $C$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \vec F\cdot d\vec \ell&=\oint_C (\hat xxz-\hat y y+\hat z x^2y)\cdot d\vec\ell\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\int_0^4\left.\left(\hat xxz-\hat y y+\hat z x^2y\right)\right|_{y=z=0}\cdot (-\hat x)\,dx}\\\\
&+\color{red}{\int_0^4 \left.\left(\hat xxz-\hat y y+\hat z x^2y\right)\right|_{x=y=0}\cdot (\hat z)\,dz}\\\\
&+\int_0^4 \left.\left(\hat xxz-\hat y y+\hat z x^2y\right)\right|_{y=0, z=4-x}\cdot \left(\hat x-\hat z\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{0}+\color{red}{0}+\int_0^4 (4x-x^2)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{32}{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: from the problem C encloses $S_1$. In the solution u have given, C encloses $S_2$. Actually we need to consider $S_1$ right? pls correct me if i am going wrong

Comment: I believe you stated that the $x-z$ was excluded from the surface if interest.  If that is indeed the case, then the analysis posted herein this solution is correct.

Comment: I did not understand sign convention. If i stand from A (as shown in image uploaded above) and move upwards (as shown by arrow sign), i find the pyramid on left hand side. So the direction i concluded is anticloackwise. can you pls explain how you have taken direction. Pls....

Comment: Use the right-hand rule.  The contour that bounds the surface with outer unit normal $-\hat y$ is traversed from $A$ to $0$ to $B$.  The thumb of your right hand points outward and in the $-\hat y$ direction and your fingers curl around from $A$ to $0$ to $B$.

Comment: OK. Now i got it. I need to apply on $S_2$ instead i am doing it on $S_1$ which is wrong. Thanks a lot for patiently clarifying things :)

Comment: Pleased to hear this was useful.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: can u tell me where to accept? i just voted ur answer up.